Meaning of 挨拶も無視かよ
A boy with black hair 竹田タケヒロ was caught by his dad skipping school with his friends:

I don't get what the brown-haired boy meant by 挨拶も無視かよ. It looks like a sort of rhetorical question and it seems to mean "you think that he (竹田's dad) will ignore your greeting?" but it still doesn't make sense to me.

This is not a rhetorical question. This か(よ) is more of an exclamation marker rather than a genuine question marker. It's the same か(よ) as in そうか ("I see") or お前かよ ("Oh it's you!").
This 挨拶も無視かよ just means "He (=the guy with brown suspenders) even ignored my greeting!". This も is "even", and it replaced を.
